# How can I view the percentage of new users that get to a specific page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to know what percentage of new users get to the URL: `/thankyou`

I've worked out how to find the absolute number of unique visits for new users, as follows:

Under *Behaviour -> Site Content -> All pages*, click on `/thankyou` row in table, then "Add Segment" -> "New Users"

But I can't find a way to show this as a percentage of all new user visits. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To know the percentage of new users against existing users that visited a page:

- On site content, go to **All pages**
- As a secondary dimension select **User type**

To know the percentage of new users that visited a page related to the site, you must do a segment:

- Click **Add segment**, then **New users**, then apply.
- In **All pages** you will now see both segments: all sessions and new users with the number of page views and percentages

Comment: I think the question was about how to view what *percentage* of new users end up on a certain page, not what percentage of users on a page is new. Is there a way to do that?